# Fly way sbt not working when sbt.version in project/build.properties is 1.2.8

Tags: sbt, flyway, sbt-plugin

Fly way sbt not working when sbt.version in project/build.properties is 1.2.8, but works fine when sbt.version in project/build.properties is 0.13.17.

Please find below github link of simplified project to demonstrate the issue.

https://github.com/moglideveloper/FlyWaySbtCheck

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because the (old) flyway-sbt plugin you are using is build for SBT 0.13.x only.

Have a look at the new flyway-sbt site: https://github.com/flyway/flyway-sbt

Use `addSbtPlugin("io.github.davidmweber" % "flyway-sbt" % "6.2.0")` in your `plugin.sbt` if you want to use flyway with SBT 1.x.